# Get scaled image dimensions for spark image

Tags: image, flex4

Is there an equivalent to contentWidth and contentHeight for spark images?

I can get the size of the image component itself, as well as the sourceWidth and sourceHeight properties to get the unscaled size of the image.

But I can't work out the scaled image width and height of the source as displayed in the image component.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Was just trying to solve this exact issue. An adequate solution I found was to use `IMAGE_ID.transform.pixelBounds.height` (or width). Note that this won't be set until after the `updateComplete` event fires for the image. No idea why FLEX doesn't have a simple scaledWidth property.

Answer (score 1):

Try extending the Spark `Image` component to include 2 new read-only properties to provide the *scaled* width and height as an equivalent to `contentWidth` and `contentHeight`.

The following will create 2 new bindable properties to return the actual scaled width and height of the image displayed inside the Spark `Image` component.

```
/**
 * Returns the width of the image display taking into account the actual 
 * constraints of the container.  If no scaling has occurred the actual
 * width of the control is returned.
 */ 
[Bindable(event="scaledWidthChanged")]
public function get scaledWidth():Number
{
    var num:Number = this.width;

    if (scaleMode == "letterbox")
    {
        try
        {
            if ( (width > 0) && (sourceWidth < sourceHeight) )
            {
                num = (sourceWidth/sourceHeight) * width;                       
            }                   
        }
        catch(e:Error)
        {
            num = this.width;
        }
    }

    return num;
}

/**
 * Returns the height of the image display taking into account the actual 
 * constraints of the container.  If no scaling has occurred the actual
 * height of the control is returned.
 */ 
[Bindable(event="scaledHeightChanged")]
public function get scaledHeight():Number
{
    var num:Number = this.width;

    if (scaleMode == "letterbox")
    {
        try
        {
            if ((height > 0) && (sourceHeight < sourceWidth))
            {
                num = (sourceHeight/sourceWidth) * height;
            }                   
        }
        catch(e:Error)
        {
            num = this.height;
        }
    }

    return num;
}
```